# How to organize data frame with several variables in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When I organize data frame with 1 variable, it works well.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.normal(45, 9, 10000)
source = {"Genotype": ["CV1"]*10000, "AGW": a}
df=pd.DataFrame(source)
df
```

However, when I add more variables, it does not work.

import numpy as np

```
a = np.random.normal(45, 9, 10000)
b = np.random.normal(35, 10, 10000)

source = {"Genotype": ["CV1"]*10000 + ["CV2"]*10000, 
          "AGW": a + b}
df=pd.DataFrame(source)
df
```

and it says "ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length"

I think the AGW column calculates actual a + b which results in 10,000 rows, not array numbers vertically. I want to make data frame with two columns with 20,000 rows.

Could you let me know how to do it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) for join 2 numpy arrays:

```
source = {"Genotype": ["CV1"]*10000 + ["CV2"]*10000, 
          "AGW": np.hstack((a, b))}
df=pd.DataFrame(source)
```

Or join `list`s:

```
source = {"Genotype": ["CV1"]*10000 + ["CV2"]*10000, 
          "AGW": list(a) + list(b)}
df=pd.DataFrame(source)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I have one more question. In this data frame, when I want to make a graph, how can I indicate CV1 and CV2? For example, sns.boxplot(data=df.["AGW"], df["AGW"]). I don't know how to indicate AGW of CV1 or CV2. Could you let me know about that? Many thank!!!

Comment: @Jin.W.Kim - hmmm, for ploting not missing `y` column? `sns.boxplot(x='AGW', y='col', hue='Genotype', data=df)`

Comment: This code works well, sns.boxplot(x='Genotype', y='AGW', hue='Genotype', data=df) Thank you so much!!